# Image of integrally closed ring under fraction field automorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, integral-domain

> Consider an integrally closed domain $A$, and a field automorphism $\phi$ of its fraction field $K$. Is it true that $\phi$ sends $A$ in $A$?

I tried using Hartogs's theorem $$A=\bigcap_{p\in \rm Spec A} A_p$$ but it didn't help me.

Probably it is something obvious, and one does not even need Hartogs. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried taking an element of the form $\phi(x)$ and showing that it is integral over $A$?

Comment: Yes: the problem is that, once I write $\phi(x)=a/b$, I get a polynomial in $A[X]$, $bX-a$, which I'd like to manipulate in order to have a monic polynomial...

Comment: The reason you find it difficult to see this is because it is false. Try $A=k[t]$ and $\phi(t)=t^{-1}$.

Comment: @Mohan So you are saying we must look carefully at the extension $K / K^\phi$ where $K^\phi$ is the fixed field ? In your counter-example $K/K^\phi = k(t)/k$

Comment: @user1952009 One must study $K/K^{\phi}$, but may not help. In the above example, without changing $K,\phi$, if I took $A=k[t,t^{-1}]$, you would be ok.